# Find and change multiple strings in the entire registry using powershell commands

Tags: string, powershell, find, key, registry

I'm trying to make a script to change values in the entire registry in all keys and subkeys for a string called "Value" and make it 0. So whenever string "Value" is found, it's value must be changed to "0".
I came to the following, but unfo all I get is errors.

```
$Registry = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::*"
Get-ChildItem -path $Registry -recurse -name 'Value'
Set-ItemProperty -path $Registry -name 'Value' "0"
```

I'm still trying to figure out some of the powershell commands.
If anyone can assist me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Making changes on the whole registry so haphazardly could be dangerous.  Can you maybe narrow down the path a bit?

Comment: Hi. Yes. HKLM\System should also work. Even though, once I get it, I can give multiple commands for the other folders as well, if needed.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to break your Window installation to be honest lol. Why would you want to change all the values, without knowing what the key is?

Comment: I know what the key is, it's just spread out all over the registry. And yes, I do know what I have to change, but I don't know how to change it fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

- **Caveat**: As noted, blindly updating registry values in entire registry key subtrees, without verifying that such updates are appropriate for each key, is problematic.
- As a safety measure, the [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command below *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Registry | 
  Where-Object Property -contains Value | 
  Set-ItemProperty -Name Value -Value 0 -WhatIf
```

The value of the `.Property` property of each registry key emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) contains the *names* of each key's values<sup>[1]</sup>, so `-contains Value`  only returns true if a given key has a value by that name.
Note the use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) in the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Name` parameter isn't a *filter* (to which you can pass a filter pattern), it is a *switch* that tells `Get-ChildItem` to output only the (relative) *paths* of the matching items, as *strings*, instead of the usual *objects* representing the provider items.
- If you want one command to act on the output of another, you need to connect them via the `|`, the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-), as shown at the top.

---

<sup>[1] With registry paths, `Get-ChildItem` emits [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) instances, but decorates them with additional properties, using PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763). `.Property` is such an ETS property, and it wraps a call to the instance's [`.GetValueNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames) method, passing the array of values through except for one modification: the *unnamed* registry value, whose in the .NET APIs is simply the *empty string*, is translated into the name `(default)`.</sup>